# Mixing normal maps not working

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting

I am working with data from a game written for DirectX and I'm using OpenGL.
I have managed to sort out 99 % of everything regarding translations of the textures and they look correct on the terrain.

Here's the problem I'm having..
I know mixing normals together directly doesn't work very well. I have read that there is a workable method but I was never able to get satisfactory results.
Here's the basics on what I'm doing.

There are 4 textures per map section.. Three of them have matching normal maps. One of them is the color base and is never translated.. It's mixed in after the translations. I keep track on this texture and send a value to the shader that is used as a mask to avoid translating the color texture or using its NON-existent normal map. I have confirmed that the masking is working by rendering the different textures, normal maps and color map.

The textures are NOT in the same order.. That is to say, though the textures might be the same, they are out of order. The first texture might be rocks and the second grass in one section but its adjoining neighbor might have these 2 reversed. I thought about sorting them but not all sections contain the same textures.

So... What I do is mask the textures and normal maps and do the math on the normal maps individually and sum them. I didn't think that the order of the maps would matter but apparently I'm mistaken? Maybe the transformed textures need the normals translated? I am transforming the normal maps but not the normals themselves.

Here's my code for masking and calculating the NdotL:

```
MixLevel = texture2D(mixtexture, mix_coords.xy).rgba;

//Which ever is the blend color can't be translated.
t1 = mix(texture2D(layer_1, color_uv), t1, mask_2.r);
t2 = mix(texture2D(layer_2, color_uv), t2, mask_2.g);
t3 = mix(texture2D(layer_3, color_uv), t3, mask_2.b);
t4 = mix(texture2D(layer_4, color_uv), t4, mask_2.a);

//Now we mix our textures
vec4 base;
base  = t4 * MixLevel.a ;
base += t3 * MixLevel.b ;
base += t2 * MixLevel.g ;
base += t1 * MixLevel.r ;

//Get our normal maps.
n1.rgb = normalize(2.0 * n1.rgb - 1.0);
n2.rgb = normalize(2.0 * n2.rgb - 1.0);
n3.rgb = normalize(2.0 * n3.rgb - 1.0);
n4.rgb = normalize(2.0 * n4.rgb - 1.0);

//-------------------------------------------------------------
//There is no good way to add normals together and not destroy them.
//We have to do the math on each one THAN add them together.
vec3 N = normalize(n);
vec3 L = normalize(lightDirection);

PN4 = normalize(TBN * n4.rgb)* mask_2.a;
PN3 = normalize(TBN * n3.rgb)* mask_2.b;
PN2 = normalize(TBN * n2.rgb)* mask_2.g;
PN1 = normalize(TBN * n1.rgb)* mask_2.r;

float NdotL = 0.0;
NdotL = NdotL + (max(dot(PN4, L), 0.0) * MixLevel.a );
NdotL = NdotL + (max(dot(PN3, L), 0.0) * MixLevel.b );
NdotL = NdotL + (max(dot(PN2, L), 0.0) * MixLevel.g );
NdotL = NdotL + (max(dot(PN1, L), 0.0) * MixLevel.r );
```

Update:
As requested I'm attaching some more code:
This is the section in the fragment shader that does the texture transform:

```
    //calcualte texcoords for mix texture.
float scale = 256.0/272.0;
vec2 mc;
mc = color_uv;
mc *= scale;
mc += .030303030;// = 8/264
mix_coords = mc.xy;
// layer 4 ---------------------------------------------
vec2 tv4;
tv4 = vec2(dot(-layer3U, Vertex), dot(layer3V, Vertex));
t4 = texture2D(layer_4, -tv4 + .5);
n4 = texture2D(n_layer_4, -tv4 + .5);
// layer 3 ---------------------------------------------
vec2 tv3;
tv3 = vec2(dot(-layer2U, Vertex), dot(layer2V, Vertex));
t3 = texture2D(layer_3, -tv3 + .5);
n3 = texture2D(n_layer_3, -tv3 + .5);
// layer 2 ---------------------------------------------
vec2 tv2;
tv2 = vec2(dot(-layer1U, Vertex), dot(layer1V, Vertex));
t2 = texture2D(layer_2, -tv2 + .5);
n2 = texture2D(n_layer_2, -tv2 + .5);
// layer 1 ---------------------------------------------
vec2 tv1;
tv1 = vec2(dot(-layer0U, Vertex), dot(layer0V, Vertex));
t1 = texture2D(layer_1, -tv1 + .5);
n1 = texture2D(n_layer_1, -tv1 + .5);
//------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Vertex is gl_Vertex in model space. Layer0U and Layer0V are vec4 and come from the game data.
This is how the mask_2 is created in the vertex shader.

```
// Create the mask.  Used to cancel transform of color/paint texture;
mask_2 = vec4(1.0 ,1.0 ,1.0 ,1.0);
switch (main_texture){
case 1: mask_2.r = 0.0; break;
case 2: mask_2.g = 0.0; break;
case 3: mask_2.b = 0.0; break;
case 4: mask_2.a = 0.0; break;
}
```

Here is an image showing the problem with the lighting:

[image: Wrong lighting]

UPDATE: I think I know whats wrong... When the normal maps are transformed (Actually its the UVs), this leaves the normal pointing in the wrong direction.
I need help transforming the actual normal that's read at the transformed UV back to its original state, I can't remove the UV translation.. that simply reads the wrong normal for that textures pixel location. It's all wrong.
What I have to work with are the 2 vec4s that do the uv transform and the vertex. If some how I could build a 3x3 matrix using these, I might be able to multiply the normal by it and get it facing the right direction? I'm not good at advanced math and need help. (For all I know that method wont even work)
Here is an image with the specular turned up.. you can see how the normals orientation is causing lighting problems.
[image: Normals facing wrong direction]

Comment: What is the difference between your `MixLevel` and `mask_2`? Can you show the respective textures? What do you mean by translating a texture? One easy way to find out if it is a problem with the diffuse color or the lighting is to set base to a constant color. Btw, be careful if you use DirectX normal maps in OpenGL. The inverted y-axis will screw up the normals. But this would not result in the inconsistency shown in the image.

Comment: MixLevel is the linear mix for each texture.. Some call this the blend texture.. The mask_2 (which I should rename to just mask) is either a 1.0 or 0.0 depending on which texture is the color (paint) texture. ) being the color texture. The textures (other than paint) are rotated and scaled by a value that's in the game data (took a month to figure out how to use it).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the Y on the normal maps.. I'm aware of this and its looks worse flipped.. maybe because the transform is flipping it. I'm not sure. I'll add some code to my question showing how the textures are transformed and scaled. After weeks of trying things I found some code some where that worked.. but had to mess with inversions to get it looking correct. The masks is created in the vertex side of the program.

Comment: It's really hard to debug this from remote. At least, there is no apparent mistake. Have you tried the quick experiment I suggested? If you are not able to find the problem through simple means, this is probably also a good use case for NSight and its pixel debugger (assuming that you get it to run).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I found the problem.. I am reversing the textures using negative texcoords. It would seem I needed to flip the x on the norms:
N1.x *= -1.0; 
Seems to all be ok now.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Ok.. I think I actually do know what the issue is but I'm to crappy at math to find the solution..
When the textures and matching normal maps are transformed, its rotating and scaling them. This causes the normals in the normal map to face the wrong direction.. That in turn causes the lighting to be reflected in the wrong direction. I'll need to find a way to rotate the normals individually back to the proper directions.

Comment: Since the rotation is always about the local z-axis (of the local tangent frame), you just need to perform a [2D rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions) of the x- and y-components. And if you restrict the rotation to multiples of 90°, the coefficients will all be -1 or +1 and you don't need to compute the expensive trigonometric functions.

Comment: Excellent... Yes that makes sense.